# Let $∼$ be a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ and $x ∼ y \iff x=y$ or $x+y=6$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $∼$ be a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ and $x ∼ y \iff x=y$ or $x+y=6$. I proved that $∼$ is an equivalence relation.
Now I have to find a complete set of representatives. I know that $[a]_∼ := \{b \in \mathbb{R} \mid b ∼ a\}$, but I don't know how to use this to find a CSR.

Comment: @md2perpe y=x=$\mathbb{R}$ or y=6-x ?

Comment: Correct. So what is $[x]_\sim$? What ordered pairs does it contain?

Comment: For x=y then [x] = {..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...}. For x != y, [x] = {{0, 6}, {1, 5}, {2, 4}, ....}

Comment: No. $[x]_\sim$ contains pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x\sim y.$

Comment: Consider a specific case. Take $x=4.$ For what values of $y$ do we have $x\sim y$?

Comment: When y=4 or y=2. So [x] = {(2, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 2), ..., (x, x), (x, 6-x)} ?

Comment: From where did you get $(3,3)$?

Comment: Taking x = 3: 3 ~ y <=> y = 3 or 3 + y = 6 <=> y = 3 or y = 6 - 3 = 3.

Comment: I realized that I was a bit confused myself. $[x]_\sim$ does not contain pairs. It just contains numbers, more specifically those $y$ such that $x\sim y.$

Comment: So for x = 4, [4] = {4, 2} ?

Comment: [2] = {2, 4}, [3] = {3}.

Comment: @fleablood that isn't a CSR

Comment: I thought we were finding the residue classes.  So for each $[x] = \{x,6-x\}$ we must choose one to be representative.   Why not choose $\min(x,6-x)$?  That'd give us $S = \{w\in \mathbb R|w \le 6 -w\}= \{w|2w \le 6\}=\{w|w\le 3\} = (-\infty, 3]$. Or we could have chosen $\max(x,6-x)$ to get $[3,\infty)$.  Or we could be perverse and do unnescessarily complicated weird things like $[3, 7)\cup (8,\infty)\cup [-2,-1]$ or $\{r\in \mathbb Q|r\ge 3\}\cup\{x\in \mathbb R|x\not\in \mathbb Q, x<3\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[3,\infty)\subset \mathbb R$ should be a suitable set of representatives.

For distinct $x,y \ge 3$, both $x\ne y$ and $x+y > 6$, so $x \nsim y$.

For other $x < 3$, both $6-x > 3$ and $6-x\sim x$, so $x$ is equivalent to some element in $[3, \infty)$.

Comment: Nice cleaning up.  My last answer may have been correct,  but was too complicated.   Staring, correctly,  at the line $y=6-x$ is probably another good way to convince oneself of this.

Comment: Of course one can see in the same way that $(-\infty, 3]$ would work.